# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DAL.HRM_PersonalInformations>'

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, entity-framework-4

I am trying to Get some data from Database and Bind them in Drop-Down list.. But getting following error : -

```
public virtual List<HRM_PersonalInformations>GetAssignePerson(String OCODE, int dptID){
 var query = (context.HRM_PersonalInformations.Where
             (c => c.OCODE == OCODE && c.DepartmentId == dptID)
             .Select(c => new {FullName = (c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName), c.EID})).ToList();

  return query; // It indicate error line
}
```

After that I am trying to Bind data in dropdown list and my code is following : -

```
private void FillAssignPerson()
 {
   try
     {
            string OCODE = ((SessionUser)Session["SessionUser"]).OCode;
            int dptId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAssignPerDept.SelectedValue);

            var row = enquiryBll.GetAssignePerson(OCODE, dptId).ToList();

            //const string list = "SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, EID, FirstName, LastName " +
            //                    "FROM HRM_PersonalInformations " +
            //                    "ORDER BY EID ASC"
            if (row.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlAssignPerson.Items.Clear();
                ddlAssignPerson.DataSource = row;
                ddlAssignPerson.DataTextField = "FullName";
                ddlAssignPerson.DataValueField = "EID";
                ddlAssignPerson.DataBind();
                ddlAssignPerson.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("----- Select One -----", "0"));
                ddlAssignPerson.AppendDataBoundItems = false;
            }
        }
```

Is it right way ?? Can anyone help me ? Thanks for Advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your projection you have:

```
c => new {FullName = (c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName), c.EID}
```

That's creating an instance of an anonymous typoe - not an instance of `HRM_PersonalInformations`. If those are the only two properties you need in `HRM_PersonalInformations`, you could just change it to:

```
c => new HRM_PersonalInformations {
   FullName = (c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName), 
   EID = c.EID
}
```

Or judging by your query, you may not need a projection at all. You may be fine with:

```
return context.HRM_PersonalInformations
              .Where(c => c.OCODE == OCODE && c.DepartmentId == dptID)
              .ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you only need those properties and don't really need the items of your list to be instances of `HRM_PersonalInformations`, you could just change the method's signature to be:

```
public virtual IList GetAssignePerson(...)
```

and keep the body as it is. You can't explicitly write a method declaration which specifies the anonymous type, because it doesn't have a name - but `List<T>` implements `IList`, so the above will certainly compile... it will fail if you later try to cast an element in it to `HRM_PersonalInformations` though.

EDIT: If the string concatenation is a problem, you might need to do that client-side. For example:

```
public IList GetAssignePerson(String OCODE, int dptID) {
    return context.HRM_PersonalInformations
                  .Where(c => c.OCODE == OCODE && c.DepartmentId == dptID)
                  .Select(c => new { c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.EID })
                  .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest client-side
                  .Select(c => new {
                      FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                      c.EID
                  })
                  .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I already try your first provide method... that time it doesn't recognize 'FullName' property....
When I try your last provide method and after program execute it give me following error .. 
"{"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}"

Comment: @mgsdew: Well is `FullName` a property of `HRM_PersonalInformations`? We have no idea what that type looks like. It's not clear to me what the problem in the last case is - it may be due to the string concatenation, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks a lot... It works beautifully in my project :D

Answer (score 0):

This methods awaits you HRM_PersonalInformations , why are you return anonymous type ?

It is useful to go back to the expected type

Try this code

```
 .Select(c => new HRM_PersonalInformations()
 {
     FullName  = c.FirstName 
     // set other prop 
 });
```

Comment: I already try this way... That time it doesn't recognize 'FullName' field... Because in my table there are no field of 'FullName'.. Just it contains 'FirstName' & 'LastName'..

Comment: Data model should only be used the save, update process.
you can create Business model HRM_PersonalInformationsModel and add FullName prop.
You go back Business model on GetAssignePerson method

Comment: Yes. HRM_PersonalInformation a table which contains 'FirstName' & 'LastName' properties.. Now I want FullName for showing data in Dropdown list...
How Can I create business model ? I mean process of creating business model..

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple sample,

If you want to customize data business process or UI process you need a new model for example You want to display full name in Dropdown so ,

- Add new folder MyCustomizeModels
- Add new class DropdownLookUpDecimal in MyCustomizeModels

> this DropdownLookUpDecimal class.

```
  public class DropdownLookUpDecimal
    {
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

    }
```

> You can use this class all Dropdown in the project.

```
  public  List<DropdownLookUpDecimal>GetAssignePerson(string oCode, int dptID)  
{
         var query = context.HRM_PersonalInformations.Where
             (c => c.OCODE == oCode&& c.DepartmentId == dptID)
             .Select(c => new DropdownLookUpDecimal
                 {
                     Text = c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName,
                     Value = c.EID
                 });      
  return query.ToList();  
 }
```

Just create new .cs and fill the list with the class and return List.

I hope it helped